# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

My issue is that I drag and drop images onto a website page into independent drop locations. Each drop location has their own unique id. It works fine for if you drag multiples onto the first location. But if you try to drag them to the second location the FileReader says its busy and errors.

I have been searching this site, google, and the jquery plus FileReader documentation. I cannot find an answer. I think the fact I am using proxy is causing it to never close.

So my question is either how to close it after each drop or how to fix it so it closes itself.

```
$(document).on('dragover dragenter', '.imagedroppable', function(e){
      thisVal = this;
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }).on('drop', $(this).attr('id'), function(e, ui){

      var dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
      if (dataTransfer && dataTransfer.files.length) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        $.each(dataTransfer.files, function(i, file) {
        // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
            if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
                (function(file) {
                  var reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.onload = $.proxy(
                                    function(file, $fileList, event) {
                                        nr++;
                                        var img = file.type.match('image.*') ? "<img  id=\"resizable"+nr+"\" class=\"resizable\" src='" + event.target.result + "' /> " : "";
                                        $(thisVal).find($fileList).prepend($("<span>").append(img));
                                        setResizable("resizable"+nr);
                                      }, this, file, $("#fileList"));
                  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                })(file);
            }
        });
      }
     // Build check for if its dropping on an image spot
     $(this).find(".imageinfo").remove();

  });

});
```

Comment: Not sure what's causing your issue here, I feel there is something missing... but anyway note that you don't need the FileReader at all here. All you want is to display these images, and for this all you need is the synchronous [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) `$.each(dataTransfer.files, function(i, file) { if(...) { var img = file.type.match('image.*') ? "<img ... src='" + URL.createObjectURL(file) + "' /> " : "";
 $("#fileList").prepend($("<span>").append(img));
 setResizable("resizable"+nr);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking to use PHP after this to upload them to a server if the files pass addition test (ie not porn and such) that I have not built out yet.

Comment: Yes, good to hear, you still don't need a FileReader though. Send these files directly in binary